# Почему не ставится посередине иконка

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы иконка была направлена вниз, как показано на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.marker-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 38px;
}
```

```html
<a class="marker-icon" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В коде как минимум одна незакрытая кавычка

Answer (score 2):

Всё **по центру** вроде бы

```css
.marker-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

i {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a class="marker-icon" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
</a>
```

**Второй вариант центрирование по центру экрана :**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marker-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

i {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a class="marker-icon" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Думаю автор вопроса некорректно сформулировал вопрос, в заголовке написано - "Почему не ставится иконка посередине", а в описании - "Мне нужно, чтобы иконка стояла вниз галочкой по отношению к ромбу"

Answer (score 1):

```css
.marker-icon {
  display: flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

i {
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a class="marker-icon" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
</a>
```

не понимаю вопрос. нужно что-то в этом роде?

Comment: Да,да,да! огромнейшее спасибо вы меня выручили.Уж простите  не могла разобраться. потрачено два дня на это.

Comment: Не за что. Удачи. Жду плюсик)

Comment: @ТатьянаПономаренко, вам ниже ответ написали, что нужно дать отрицательный rotate для иконки:))

Answer (score 0):

Если надо, чтобы иконка-галочка в ромбе была направлена вниз, просто примените к ней CSS-трансформацию, обратную той, что была использована для поворота ромба.

Comment: пробывала не получается